# Index existing relationships in neo4j

Tags: java, indexing, neo4j

Is it possible to add index on existing relationships.
More specifically I have a relationship called Relatadness with one property called score(score is double) and I want to index it (with java or through the web client).
How can  do that?
thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of Neo4j are you using? Anything other then 2.0 you can manually index without any trouble.

Comment: Neo4j Stable Release 1.9.3 for windows..Could you please give me some instructions cause I can't find something that works properly anywhere.
thank you for yuor answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have the relationships, you'll have to iterate through all of them. This code example will create an index called `RelatadnessIndex`, and store the relationship in the  index under a key of `score`:

```
    GlobalGraphOperations ggo = GlobalGraphOperations.at(db);
    Index<Relationship> relatadnessIndex = db.index().forRelationships("RelatadnessIndex");
    for (Relationship r : ggo.getAllRelationships()) {
        if (r.getType().name().equals("Relatadness")) {
            double score = (double) r.getProperty("score");
            relatadnessIndex.add(r, "score", score);
        }
    }
```

Note that by default Neo4j/Lucene will index the value as a String, so doing numeric range searches won't work. If you want to have it stored as a Numeric, you'll need to change to add to be this:

```
relatadnessIndex.add(r, "score", new ValueContext( score ).indexNumeric() );
```