# Can arrows get lables in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, orientdb

Can arrows between nodes get labels similar to nodes in Neo4J. Nodes can be annotated by [labels in Neo4J](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-node-labels.html).

If the answer is NO, Is there any graphDB that arrows can accept labels as well as nodes and these labels are used in their corresponding query languages?

UPDATE:
[here a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22437106/relationship-labels-and-index-in-neo4j) is asked, and the answer was NO! anything changed since then?

Answer (score 1):

A relationship ("arrow") has a single "type", which is similar to a node label. However, a relationship can only have a single type.